# How Do I Have A CountdownTimer Nested Within Another CountdownTimer?

Tags: java, android

So I have two Countdowntimers, and I want one nested within the onFinish of the other. I do not want to use a runnable because I feel it would be disadvantageous for my app because it is so hard to cancel. This seems fairly straightforward in execution, however I keep getting errors.

```
final CountDownTimer TheTimer;
    final CountDownTimer FinalTimer;

    TheTimer = new CountDownTimer((cdTime), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            button.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
            if(millisUntilFinished <= 10000){
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {


            FinalTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            }.start();

        }
    }.start();
```

Error: Cannot assign  value to final variable.

However the Ide is the one telling me to make it final

[image: Visual Aid]

What I get if I make the second timer not final
[image: What I get if I make the second timer not final]

Comment: please fix your code to be readable. Use correct variable names, remove unnecessary empty lines. This is hard to read, even if it's very simple code.

Comment: fixed and edited

Comment: The code in the screenshot and the code you provide in your question differ semantically. Please provide clean code for your question. In the codeblock in your question you are trying to call `.start()`on the  `onFinish`methods. Screenshots are not necessary to show code.

Comment: Also provide information about the errors you get: what type of error, when, etc.

Comment: The IDE is not telling you to make it a final. Make it a non-final instance field of the class.

Comment: is this better?

Comment: well it tells me to make the timer final initially, and then when I do it makes the error originally presented

Comment: why don't you separate initialization and start of the second timer? initiate the timer as final , then in the onFinish method of the first timer just call the start method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
final CountDownTimer finalTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000){
    public void onTick(long l){
        //do Stuff
    }
    public void onFinish(){
        //doStuff
    }
};    
final CountDownTimer theTimer = new CountDownTimer((cdTime), 1000){    
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){    
        button.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
        if(millisUntilFinished <= 10000){
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }    
    }    
    public void onFinish(){    
        finalTimer.start();    
    }
}.start();
```

try to set final variables as early as possible to make sure, they are properly initiated. For futur questions: please try to keep code well formated and provide enough information about the problem you have, like error codes etc.